# Sitefinity: How to use ExpandableObjectConverter with new interface

Tags: sitefinity

I have created an expandable follow the document below:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/how-to-use-expandableobjectconverter

It's working, but when I switch to the new interface(new UI) it is not working.
Could you help me to fix it?

1. new interface
   [image: new interface]
2. old interface
   [image: old interface]
3. expected with new interface
   [image: expected]

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev I have attached expected to the question.

Comment: Sorry, the screenshots look ok to me

Comment: @VeselinVasilev with the new interface, the UI doesn't have taxonomy  expandable, it should have taxonomy expandable same the third picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the UI looks like the one in point 3 of your screenshots, then you should not use a class property and the ExpandableObjectConverter.
Instead in your controller create the individual properties, maybe add a Category attribute to them.

**Update**: Documentation: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/autogenerated-widget-property-editors

Comment: Could you give me references documentation?